# Get latest result by latest date with three columns having the same value in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, greatest-n-per-group

I am new to sql and I need your help. I have a test results data in a database and I want to get the latest results.

```
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------   
| ID | TestDate   | App | Service   | Environment | Critical | High | Medium | Low |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 1  | 2020-03-01 | app | service-a | sit         | 1        | 2    | 3      | 5   |
| 2  | 2020-03-02 | app | service-b | sit         | 0        | 3    | 2      | 1   |
| 3  | 2020-03-03 | app | service-a | sit         | 0        | 1    | 5      | 3   |
```

I want to get only the latest result for service-a and then the result for service-b. I tried

```
SELECT MAX(TestDate), App, Service, Environment, Critical, High, Medium, Low from table 
GROUP BY TestDate, App, Service, Environment, Critical, High, Medium, Low;
```

but It still returns both service-a values. Removing some of the columns in `GROUP BY` will yield the nonaggregate column error.

Here is some sample data you can test with.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test_results` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `app` VARCHAR(10) NULL,
  `environment` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `service` VARCHAR(256) NULL,
  `service_version` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  `test_date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `critical` VARCHAR(256) NULL,
  `high` VARCHAR(256) NULL,
  `medium` VARCHAR(256) NULL,
  `low` VARCHAR(256) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
INSERT INTO `test_results` (`app`, `environment`, `service`, `service_version`, `test_date`, `critical`, `high`, `medium`, `low`)
VALUES ("app1", "sit", "service-a", "1.0.0", "2020-03-01 01:03:08", 1, 2, 3, 4),
 ("app1", "sit", "service-a", "1.0.1", "2020-03-03 01:03:08", 5, 7, 3, 1),
 ("app1", "sit", "service-b", "1.1.2", "2020-03-02 01:03:08", 5, 9, 6, 4),
 ("app1", "sit", "service-c", "1.0.5", "2020-03-02 01:03:08", 3, 1, 9, 4);
```

And a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c6b8c4/1) of same

EDIT: Added fiddle

Comment: @Strawberry added fiddle. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter instead of aggregating;

```
select t.*
from mytable
where t.testdate = (
    select max(t1.testdate) from mytable t1 where t1.service = t.service
)
```

Answer (score 1):

A potentially more efficient solution than a subquery with `max()` is the following;

```
SELECT t.*
FROM `table` t
   LEFT JOIN `table` t1 ON t1.service = t.service AND t1.testdate > t.testdate
WHERE t1.id IS NULL;
```

Only returning rows that do *not* successfully join in the `LEFT JOIN` ensures that we only see results where `testdate` is the highest value for that `service`.

Comment: Hi this also works for me however I prefer GMB's answer as I already have a join in order to come up with that table and I don't want to add another one. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This solution will allow you to have multiple test results on the same date and time, and still take the latest one - provided that your id is incrementing on every new record.

```
SELECT
  results.*
FROM `test_results` AS results
JOIN `test_results` AS latest_results
  ON latest_results.id = (
    SELECT id FROM `test_results` 
    WHERE service = results.service
    ORDER BY test_date DESC, id DESC LIMIT 1)
WHERE
  latest_results.id = results.id
```